# ListView setItems not updating list

Tags: java, android

I've got this in my ListView adapter,

```
public void setListItems(List<String[]> data) {
    Log.d(tag, this.data.size() + "," + data.size());
    this.data.clear();
    this.data = data;
    Log.d(tag, this.data.size() + "," + data.size());
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

My log says this:

```
10,5
0,5
```

this.data = data; is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace your

`this.data = data`

with

`this.data.addAll(data)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add new Items then replace only

```
this.data = data;
```

with

```
this.data.addAll(data);
```

And remove

```
this.data.clear();
```

Now you change and check it yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

replace tour code with this

```
public void setListItems(List<String[]> data) {
    Log.d(tag, this.data.size() + "," + data.size());
    this.data.clear();
    this.data.addAll(data);
    Log.d(tag, this.data.size() + "," + data.size());
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

when you are adding all of an array's indexes to another array you should use
function

firstArray.addAll(secondArray);

Answer (score 0):

remove this line

```
this.data.clear();
```

in your function setListItems(...).